# r lm-like line in scatterplot3d

Tags: r, 3d, scatter-plot, lm

I want to add something of the form "abline" to a 3d Scatterplot in R.

Here's my code so far:

```
plot3d <-     scatterplot3d(    Table$Unemployment,     Table$Foreigners,   
Table$Overall.crime,     color="red",     pch=20,     type="p" )
```

I cannot find the corresponding "abline" command. Is there even such a thing? Or should I use a cloud-like function?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use `rgl` instead, there is a demo using surfaces which could be easily pruned down to lines

```
library(rgl)
demo("regression")
```

Comment: the demo turns up with really cool results, however, I have no idea how to transform my data into this framework :-( Thanks however! :-)

Comment: If you want more details, provide those by giving sample data. Also check the documentation of rgl::lines3d.